# Double link list searching C++ through recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-c++

I am trying to implement searching a double link list through recursion, 
it gives me only output of first node like if the input is 1,2,3 and I am trying to search 1 then it gives me found, but if am trying to search 2 then it says not found. 
I think

```
else
{
    return search(xtemp->next, num);
}
```

is not working, it does not move forward.

```
int search(node *xtemp, int num)
{
    xtemp = head;
    if (xtemp->next == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (xtemp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (xtemp->info == num)
    {
        cout << "Target found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (xtemp->info != num)
    {
        cout << "NOt found," << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return search(xtemp->next, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: it does not gives me an error

Comment: @p156064ZeeshanHaiderSaheen, it will not give you an error. You need to *search* for the error. Debugger makes it somewhat easier.

Comment: You should step through your code and watch if variables are changing in the way you expect them to do.

Comment: okay i'll try debugger

Comment: You should not assign `xtemp = head` in each recursive call. Remove that line. And call `search(head,<target>)`

Comment: More to the point, the outside initial call to `search` should use `search(head, num)`. Inside this funciton, the line `xtemp = head;` is resetting the recursed parameter back to the global `head`, which you do NOT want. Remove that line. There should be no usage of the variable `head` directly within this function *at all*.

Comment: The function always return zero. Did you intend for it to return something useful?

Comment: @p156064ZeeshanHaiderSaheen Also you could solve that with a simple loop, no need for recursion at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have gloval variable named head... 
Look what you are doing on the first line of your function

```
 xtemp = head;
```

So, does not matter what you get in recursive call, you replace xtemp value with the head of linked list

You should call `search(head)` from main(), and don't use `xtemp=head` inside the function

Also, look at the following:

```
 if (xtemp->info == num)
    {
        cout << "Target found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (xtemp->info != num)
    {
        cout << "NOt found," << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Your recursive call will never be called since you cover all possible options with xtemp->info, If it is equal to num, it will return 0, if it is not equal to num, it will also return 0. How exactly do you want to get to recursive call ?

try this:

```
int search(node *xtemp, int num)
{
    if (xtemp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Not Found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (xtemp->info == num)
    {
        cout << "Target found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return search(xtemp->next, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you remove the line xtemp=head from the function?

Comment: i am using head everywhere in function instead of xtemp;

Comment: if a condition is true then simply it returns, i thi9nk there is no problem using return 0; is there any problem in using them.?

Comment: edited again.. And yes, there is a problem. If a condition (info==num) is true, If not, it checks if (info != num) and it definitely will be true, and it returns again. So you will never get to recursive call.

Comment: i wants to improve my recursion, what u suggest me to do.. i am practicing but it takes much time.. is there any site that can help me in my concepts..?